# How to retrieve a specific node's value in XPath?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have a XML file with this format:

```
<object>
<origin>1:1:1</origin>
<normal>2:2:2</normal>
<leafs>
    <object>
        <origin>1:1:1</origin>
        <normal>3:3:3</normal>
        <leafs>none</leafs>
    </object>
</leafs>
</object>
```

How could I retrieve the value "none" of element `<leafs>` on second level of the tree? I used this

```
XPathExpression expLeafs = xpath.compile("*[name()='leafs']");
Object resLeafs = expLeafs.evaluate(node, XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList leafsList = (NodeList) resLeafs;
if (!leafsList.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue().equals("none"))
         more code...
```

but it doesn't work because there are some empty text nodes bofore and after "none". Is there a way to deal with it like `xpath.compile("*[value()='none']")`?

Comment: *"it doesn't work because there are some empty nodes"* isn't very specific. Where are the empty nodes?

Comment: FYI, your XPath expression `"*[name()='leafs']"` is equivalent to `"leafs"`.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "empty nodes." Element nodes with no children? Text nodes with no text value? Also the behavior of your xpath evaluation depends on the value of the `node` variable, which you haven't told us about. Does it hold the root node (parent of `<object>`)? or maybe the `<object>` element node?

Comment: by empty nodes i mean text nodes with no text value and they are here: <leafs>[empty-textNode][empty-textNode][...]none[empty-textNode]</leafs>

Comment: yes @LarsH, `node` holds the `<object>` element from the current level of the tree, more precisely the second <object> element in this XML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran a simple test program using your XML file and

```
expr = xpath.compile("/object/leafs/object/leafs/text()");
```

and got the desired "none" result. If you have additional requirements, you'll have to edit your question.

Comment: Indeed, it works like that, but i have to to it dynamically because my real XML has tens, maybe hundreds of `<object>` levels.

Answer (score 1):

After a checking the code line @Lord Torgamus provided i managed to parse the document as i needed like this:

```
XPathExpression expLeafs = xpath.compile("*[name()='leafs']");
Object resLeafs = expLeafs.evaluate(node, XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList leafsList = (NodeList) resLeafs;

Node nd = leafsList.item(0);

XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("text()");
Object resultObj = expr.evaluate(nd, XPathConstants.NODE);
String str = expr.evaluate(nd).trim();
System.out.println(str);
```

and the output is "none" with no other empty text node.

Comment: I wonder if the difference is that you used XPathConstants.NODE instead of NODESET -- that should return the first text() node selected by the expression. Your two XPath expressions should be equivalent to one, `"*[name()='leafs'][1]/text()"` (which is equivalent to `"leafs/text()"`), so your code can be simplified quite a bit.

Comment: @LarsH, the code line where i used NODE is an empty statement,it's not used, i forgot to delete it before posting. About the `"*[name()='leafs'][1]/text()"`, i tried it but before reading your comment without the `[1]` and it didn't work. Also, i need the first 3 lines of code, because i use the `Node nd` from `leafsList' further in my class.

Comment: good point, I missed the fact that `resultObj` is unused. Regarding the expression, I'm curious why it "didn't work," but without more information on what result was given, I wouldn't hazard a guess. But I would try `"string(leafs)"` which gives the concatenation of all text nodes descended from the (first) child element named 'leafs'.

Comment: @LarsH, i suppose it didn't work because the XML was manualy generated in NetBeans' XML editor, and because i used it's sugestions to close the tag i've just opened and not typed it manually those empty text nodes may have occured. The output for a `System.out.println(leafsList.item(i).getNodeValue())` was `[empty space],[none]`